# Redis cache not working with atlassian-connect-spring-boot-jpa-starter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-redis, atlassian-connect

I am using sample from
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-cache
Sample project work as it is when i run using

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Predis
```

However when i add dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.connect</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-connect-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.connect</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-connect-spring-boot-jpa-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

I get below exception

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:557)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.setResourceAccessor(ServiceLocator.java:129)
        at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.<init>(ServiceLocator.java:69)
        at liquibase.servicelocator.CustomResolverServiceLocator.<init>(CustomResolverServiceLocator.java:16)
        at org.springframework.boot.liquibase.LiquibaseServiceLocatorApplicationListener$LiquibasePresent.replaceServiceLocator(LiquibaseServiceLocatorApplicationListener.java:56)
        at org.springframework.boot.liquibase.LiquibaseServiceLocatorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LiquibaseServiceLocatorApplicationListener.java:45)
        at org.springframework.boot.liquibase.LiquibaseServiceLocatorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LiquibaseServiceLocatorApplicationListener.java:35)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:68)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:137)
        at sample.cache.SampleCacheApplication.main(SampleCacheApplication.java:31)
        ... 6 more Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:734)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:434)
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.fill(Manifest.java:441)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine(Manifest.java:375)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.readLine(Manifest.java:409)
        at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:376)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:199)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:69)
        at liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator.setResourceAccessor(ServiceLocator.java:118)
        ... 20 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some JARs have failed to download correctly with maven and the JARs cannot be read

You can try and find the offending jar and delete it from within the `.m2` folder yourself, or just run `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` to wipe everything then re-compile or I personally prefer a `mvn install` to grab the test dependencies etc.

There are some more options for the dependency plugin thatcan make it more fine grained.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html